# iText.Licensing.Base.Util.SigningUtil' threw an exception/NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: itext, licensing

I am attempting to get a free trial license to iText.pdfxfa running.  It has been a slog; I have gotten one error after another requesting a new iText or Microsoft .dll to be added.  But now I am getting an error I cannot diagnose.  As the title says of this question states:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'iText.Licensing.Base.Util.SigningUtil' threw an exception.'
>
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Has anyone seeing this error before?  Following is my simple (vb.net) test code:

````
Imports System.IO
Imports iTextSharp
Imports Jint
Imports Microsoft.Extensions.Options
Imports iText.Licensing.Base.LicenseKey
Imports iTextSharp.tool.xml.xtra.xfa

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim fin As System.IO.FileStream = New FileStream("C:\burn\SW1C.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        Dim fout As System.IO.FileStream = New FileStream("C:\burn\SW1C_flat.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)

        Dim theLicense As New FileInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\" & "6fda970becee70da9b732e07c775d823cbdabb301394a4001408f7a570069092.json")

        LoadLicenseFile(theLicense)

     

        Dim theFlattener As New XFAFlattener
        theFlattener.Flatten(fin, fout)
    End Sub
End Module```

The error occurs at "LoadLicenseFile".  My target framework is 7.0.

ANY help is appreciated!
````

Comment: being on a Trial entitles you to commercial support. I'd try that ([support portal](https://itext.freshdesk.com/support/home)).